# YouTube Analytics API Localhost 8080 error

Tags: python, youtube-api

My script is the same as https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/pull/45/commits/e5ec5453233c287cbfe1ecd296ae0ed18c4ce523 (written in Python) where I specified the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret_xxx.com.json"

The client secret is created under OAuth 2.0 client IDs as "other".
When I run it, it throws the following error:
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
While the url is http://localhost:8080/?code=4/Wulz_B8fgMauanVxtPocdgwE1sNndZZe6BGrVLI7wLU#

Any idea what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the script, execute python file_name.py --noauth_local_webserver.
Here are the steps:

1)      Execute “python youtube_api.py --noauth_local_webserver”
        It will show you a long URL

2)      Copy that URL and open in a browser

3)      It will ask you to login on your Google account and pick the channel

4)      It will show you a “Verification Code” (something like 4/j6KgOnbVU08kbBpi-GVOq9D6p-Vm6inOQUOJiTYWQqs)

5)      Copy Verification Code and paste within the EC2 window. Click Enter
You're done. From now on it will execute whatever parameters you indicate within the script

Answer (score 0):

According to [Youtube guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/registering_an_application), you should choose an oauth type "Web application" not "other".

After that you also need to authorize your origin, in this case your local server URL, http://localhost:8080.

Moreover, don't forget to specify your redirect URIs, in your case, http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback in the Google Dev Console.

Comment: Noogui, python is an installed application and not web application.
I was able to fix the issue: Basically executing “python youtube_api.py --noauth_local_webserver” and not “python youtube_api.py” was all I was missing.

Comment: sorry, you should post your resolution as answer then and accept it :)